# Which USB wifi adapter has best open source driver on Linux (linux-firmware ...) support?

Tags: linux, wifi, wireless, network-adapter, adapter

I need a WiFi adapter for my Linux desktop computer. The modern WiFi adapter usually lack the support for Linux platform (don't not need manually installation (include in linux-firmware)), but manually driver installation is also acceptable.

The PCI-E adapter is not in the range of consideration. I just want a USB WiFi adapter.

It don't have to support very latest standard. It just need to support 2.4GHz (and 5GHz optional), 802.11b/g/n is OK.

Does this kind of USB WiFi adapter exist?

Comment: Are you looking for open source or just Linux support? Most older Qualcomm and Broadcom devices have decent support but require binary blobs. Also what's your kernel version and distro?

Comment: @JanDorniak, later than 4.19. I use several distro, Debian, Fedora, Arch Linux etc.